# How does resampling in AdaBoost (exactly) work?

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, boosting, ensemble-learning, adaboost

Overall, I like to think that I understand how AdaBoost works, i.e., fitting a weak learner, calculating the error, calculating the confidence / amount of say of the learner, updating the sample weights. However, I'm not 100% sure about the last step of resampling for the next iteration -- I'm aware that the alternative is to directly consider the updated weights if learner uses the weighting information during training (which not all learner support).

Let's assume I have a dataset X = [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5] so my initial "sample" is simply D_0 = X with all sample weights initialized with 1/5. Now let's assume that my first learner misclassifies x1 and x2. This means that the sample weights for x1 and x2 increase (all others decrease). Now I can sample D_1 from D_0 using the new sample weight, resulting in, say, D_1 = [x2, x1, x1, x5, x2]. I also re-initialize all the sample weights in D_1 with 1/5, right?

As far as I understand, now I do the same steps -- fitting a weak learner, calculating the error, calculating the confidence / amount of say of the learner, updating the sample weights -- for D_1.

But now my questions is: How do I sample D_2?

- Sampling from D_1 is straightforward but would mean that D_2 could never include sample x4 from the original dataset. That feels kind of odd to me.
- Sampling from D_0 would give all samples a chance to be picked, but than it's not clear to me how to use the weights. Firstly, D_2 gives me no weight for x4 and some samples (here: x1 and x2) are duplicated in D_2.

Or maybe I'm missing something more fundamental. Unfortunately, all examples/tutorials/illustrations/etc. I've found only go from D_0 to D_1 using sampling but then stop and it's simply not clear to me how to get from D_1 to D_2 and so on.

Comment: Is resampling necessary to AdaBoost? I could not understand what is our expectation of D_m for next iteration.

Comment: *I'm aware that the alternative is to directly consider the updated weights if learner uses the weighting information during training (which not all learner support).* That's how you do it. You keep updating the weights in the same way, but instead of using the weights to calculate a weighted GI metric, you draw from the original dataset where each sample is chosen with probability proportional to the weights.